# Python: Using multiprocessing and pytables together

Tags: python, file, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pytables

I have used pytables to create a table that has approximately 200 columns and 200,000 rows.

I want to calculate the Spearmans rank correlation between each column. I am using the function scipy.stats.spearmanr to do this serially, but it takes a very very long time to run.

I can get multiprocessing working using the following snippet

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
pool.apply_async(stats.spearmanr, args=(table.col(col_a), table.col(col_b)))
```

where col_a and col_b are the two columns being compared.

From my understanding, the main process has to get the data from the table and then transfer it to the worker process - which in my mind is not very efficient. Assuming that my understanding is correct, then surely it would be quicker for each process to read in its own data from the table so that the data transfer between processes doesn't need to occur.

Is this possible, and if so how do I go about implementing it?

Comment: Hi, that should be possible, you need to define a function which imports pytables and goes and reads the part of the table that you need and does the calculation. I believe this is not a great idea, because, there will be multiple processes reading your data file, which may not be very efficient.  In the end, it all depends on where your bottleneck is (CPU or file IO).